# Angular CLI: Change REST API URL on build

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-webpack

I want to remove my local server prefix from my REST API URLs (example, http://localhost:8080) when building for production (`ng build --prod`).

I get that it's something to do with the environment file `environment.prod.ts`, but can't find any examples of making use of them to achieve the aforementioned.

Would be great if someone helps me get started!

Comment: Use an APP_INITIALIZER to DI your service to pull in a config json file. See an example here https://stackoverflow.com/a/65634071/249097

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Dont hard code the URL.
Use **environment.prod.ts** and **environment.ts** files which are inside src/environments.
for localhost, in environment.ts file use some variable to save your url.

```
export const environment = 
{
    production: false,
    API_URL: 'http://localhost:8080',
};
```

for production, in environment.prod.ts

```
export const environment = 
{
    production: true,
    API_URL: 'http://api.productionurl.com',
};
```

When using in your code import the variable,

```
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';
....
....

private API_URL= environment.API_URL;
```

whenever your are using for production use angular cli command option

```
ng build --env=prod
```

The file contents for the current environment will overwrite these during build.
The build system defaults to the dev environment which uses `environment.ts`, but if you do
`ng build --env=prod` then `environment.prod.ts` will be used instead.
The list of which env maps to which file can be found in `.angular-cli.json`.

For more queries refer,
https://angular.io/guide/deployment

Comment: you are hardcoding the URL too. Putting it in another file with a special name like `environment` is not making you avoid hardcoding :shrug:. API URLs should be set via environment variables. A variable inside a file called `environment` it's not an environment variable.

Comment: @Sebastian interesting, could you suggest how best to set environment variables for API URLS?

Comment: @NarayanDheerajKumar the approach I used with docker containers goes like this: before you start your webserver to load your static html and js files, you parse your environment variables and inject them into your `index.html` file. For this to work seamlessly, you must craft your `index.html` with, for example, variable placeholders.

Comment: @NarayanDheerajKumar I explained in big detail in the answer I just posted: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47426721/angular-cli-change-rest-api-url-on-build/65322383#65322383

Answer (score 4):

## Relative URLs

Putting an API_URL in your environment config is a good idea, but if your API and client app is being served from the same server or domain, you can **use relative URLs instead**.  It is much easier to set up and simplifies your build process.

Here is some code that would live in an API service.

```
  get(path: string, params: HttpParams = new HttpParams()): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(`/api${path}`, { params })
      .pipe(catchError(this.formatErrors));
  }
```

If you are using the environment.API_URL, you can still configure that value to be blank.

This can be helpful if you are serving your app and API from separate localhost servers in a development environment.  For example, you might `ng serve` from localhost:4200 and run your API from a PHP, C#, Java, etc. backend on localhost:43210.  You will need the API_URL config for development.

```
  get(path: string, params: HttpParams = new HttpParams()): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(`${environment.api_url}/api${path}`, { params })
      .pipe(catchError(this.formatErrors));
  }
```

As a bonus, here is an example of ApiService that is an injectable object you can use in your app!

https://github.com/gothinkster/angular-realworld-example-app/blob/63f5cd879b5e1519abfb8307727c37ff7b890d92/src/app/core/services/api.service.ts

Pay attention to the base ref in your main HTML page as well.

Answer (score 4):

### DEV/PROD parity approach

One way to this approach using containers is by parsing your environment files before you launch your webserver. This assumes that your are following a good practice, that is, you aren't serving your angular application via `ng`.

For example, a rudimentary approach would be to craft your `index.html` with your desired configuration, this is just an example, do it how you see best:

```
<script>
  window.config = {
     ENV_VAR1: 'ENV_VAR1_PLACEHOLDER',
     ENV_VAR2: 'ENV_VAR2_PLACEHOLDER',
     ....
  }
</script>
```

Before launching your webserver with your static content, use a script that verifies and matches valid environment variables from your configuration `window.config` with your actual environment variables.

This is doable with `sed` for instance, or if you want to go pro, you may also use `[jq][1]`.

After your validation is done, your `index.html` has the `window.config` object configured following the [dev-prod parity approach from 12factors](https://12factor.net/dev-prod-parity).

Running your docker container would be just,

`docker run -it -e ENV_VAR1="my development value" ...`

and for production,

`docker run -it -e ENV_VAR1="my production value" ...`

Comment: This seems like a good answer @Sebastian but it needs a bit about how to make Angular compile when the window.config variable is not in it's rendering scope, causing build failures.

Comment: @Routhinator `window` may be used in the `environment.ts` file and you export values from there. As javascript is runtime, it won't matter at build time if that object is undefined.

Answer (score 2):

You will find the URL configuration in **environment.ts** and **environment.prod.ts** file.
Don't put hardcoded URL while calling the API. A good practice is to read the API URLs from environment.ts and environment.prod.ts file

For the local environment use environment.ts

```
export const environment = 
{
    production: false,
    API_URL: 'http://localhost:8080',
};
```

For the production environment use environment.prod.ts

```
export const environment = 
{
    production: true,
    API_URL: 'http://api.productionurl.com',
};
```

Comment: Why Prod url has api before produtuonurl.com?

Comment: @NithinPaul it might be just an example. Another would be valid as well like `http://my.custom.domain.api.prod.com` or whatever you want.

Answer (score 1):

One possible way to achieve that is, to define different base URLs based on `isDevMode()` in your code. For example,

```
import { isDevMode } from '@angular/core';

// ...
let baseUrl: string;
if (isDevMode()) {
    baseUrl = "http://localhost:8080/";
} else {
    baseUrl = "http://api.myprodserver.com/";
}
// ...
```

Edit: This is meant to be for illustration. You'll likely want to use some type of (env-dependent) "config" in real code.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to hard code the API_URL as mentioned above just use your **environment.prod.ts** file. 
Set-:

1. production = true.
2. Change the API_URL to your desired url.
3. Now run the command **ng build --prod=true**

It worked for me I guess, will work for you too.

Answer (score 1):

Hardcoding in this or another way an address to the API server is not a good way.
The API URL should be stored in a configuration file possible to change without recompiling whole application. I think this is a way you should do it: [Editable config file](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/angular-how-to-editable-config-files/)