# Can we change root APIURL in angular 8 without building project with environment development or production from CLI

Tags: angular, angular8

Do we need to build project two times with prod and development, or is there any other way to change the root URL of API pointed on different server and root url change without building the project.

Comment: Without building in production, How do you think of deploying it? You don't need to build in development. Use `ng serve`.

Comment: I got the solution  https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/12442

Answer (score 6):

I don't understand why a lot of people keep their API URL root in `environment.ts` files! What if I want to deploy my production build in multiple staging/testing environments? What if I want to distribute the applications to clients so that they can install this locally?

We DO have a very easy way to achieve this and interestingly this is also mentioned in the Angular official [docs](https://angular.io/guide/http#requesting-data-from-a-server) and in one of the [demos](https://stackblitz.com/angular/ryaqjjalxjj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fconfig%2Fconfig.service.ts). Here is the summary.

Create a json file in your assets folder. The folder `assets` is chosen only because, by default Angular is configured to serve files from there. You can keep the config file anywhere as long as you make a corresponding change in `angular.json` as well. I call it `app.config.json` and this is its content.

```
{
    "apiBaseUrl": "https://localhost:5001"
}
```

I prefer to create a typed object to keep our configuration data, although it is optional. if you want a typed object, create `app.config.ts` with the following contents.

```
interface AppConfig {
    apiBaseUrl: string;
}
```

Now you need an `Injectable` to pull this file into browser. Create a service `app-config.service.ts` (I recommend using the CLi command `ng g service AppConfig` and it will create a file `app-config.service.ts` with a class name `AppConfigService`). Here is the highlights.

```
appConfig: AppConfig;
constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

loadAppConfig() {
    this.http
        .get<AppConfig>("/assets/app.config.json")
        .pipe(
            retry(2), // Retry 3 times, if fails
        )
        .subscribe(
            (data: AppConfig) => {
                 // Success
                this.appConfig = { ...data };
                console.log("client config loadded", this.appConfig);
            },
            (error) => {
                // Failure
                console.log(error);
            }
        );
}
```

You basically request the JSON file and keep the settings in the local variable `appConfig`. Now we need a way to call `loadAppConfig()` when the application loads for the first time.

Enter `APP_INITIALIZER`. Angular [defines it as](https://angular.io/api/core/APP_INITIALIZER)

> A DI token that you can use to provide one or more initialization
> functions.

You can hook it up in your `app.module.ts` in the `providers` section like below.

```
providers: [
    {
        provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
        multi: true,
        deps: [AppConfigService],
        useFactory: (appConfigService: AppConfigService) => {
            return () => {                    
                return appConfigService.loadAppConfig();
            };
        },
    },
],
bootstrap: [AppComponent],
```

Now that your service and its `loadAppConfig()` method are guaranteed to be called at startup, we can start injecting this in to any of our components/services. Just call the service instance and we have our `appConfig` object available.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the wonderful answer.. I just wanted to know that I am currently updating api url after aws ec2 instance created and then building the docker image... when going for terraform, this affects because creating EC2 itself is a part of deployment. can u pls help on this?

Answer (score 0):

We can create a config.json file in project directory and in app.component.ts read the new configuration setting without rebuilding the project.
I got solution here 
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/12442