# Change rest API in file json without redeploy

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript, rest

I've implement call API from file Json it working. But the problem is I want to change path API in file json without redeploy. I've try but it not working. It is possible to implement it?

**assets/config/config.json**

```
{
"urls":{
  "apiBaseUrl": "https://demored.ddns.net:59443",
  "path": "/demored/api"
 }
}
```

**assets/config/config.ts**

```
const config = require("./config.json");
export const URLS = Object({

  "apiBaseUrl": config.urls.apiBaseUrl,
  "path": config.urls.path
})
```

**environment.prod.ts**

```
import { URLS } from '../assets/api-url/config';
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  
  apiBaseUrl: URLS.apiBaseUrl,
  path: URLS.path,
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible and it looks like you are on the right path. Since your API url is split out into config.json, you should be able to make changes to the API url without redeploying/rebuilding your project assuming you are loading the JSON file correctly. There is a good solution here,

[Can we change root APIURL in angular 8 without building project with environment development or production from CLI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58972187/can-we-change-root-apiurl-in-angular-8-without-building-project-with-environment)

Comment: Thanks for your answer.., So with this method it did not need to use environment.prod.ts?