# Angular8: HttpClient post to server's address

Tags: angular, httpclient

During development, my server is running on localhost. 
So my code is:

```
this.http.post ('http://localhost:8000',body).subscribe(...
```

But after deployment, my server is running on another IP (e.g 128.3.130.61)
This remote PC contains also the 'dist' folder.

I want the address in http.post to be always the server's one.

How can I do it without running "ng build" ?

Thank you,
Zvika

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular CLI: Change REST API URL on build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47426721/angular-cli-change-rest-api-url-on-build)

Comment: Read https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/stories/proxy.md and https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-application-environments

Comment: window.location.origin will return ip:port

Answer (score 1):

Use the environment files to manage these URL's. There will be two files environment.prod.ts and environment.stage.ts under environments folder which can be used to dynamically change these URL's.

**environment.ts**

```
export const environment = 
{
    production: false,
    API_URL: 'http://localhost',
};
```

**environment.prod.ts**

```
export const environment = 
{
    production: true,
    API_URL: 'https://128.3.130.61',
};
```

Import this environment in your respective service and use it accordingly.

**app.service.ts**

```
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';
private API_URL= environment.API_URL;
```

And during production, mention the command as

```
ng build --env=prod
```

Hope it helps!